# Compress in-memory PHP array to a .tar.gz file (PHAR?)

Tags: php, compression, gzip, phar

I have a large in-memory array of xml-files as string.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to create a readable/extractable .tar.gz file from PHP (5.3).

Currently i'm using [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/945-PHP-Create-tar-gzip-bzip2-zip-extract-tar-gzip-bzip2-.html).

But :

- It does not look maintained
- It requires files (so i'm creating thousands of files from my memory array which are useless a few ms later)

So i'm looking for a efficient way to handle a .tar.gz file, most important point is to be able to easily put files in it with a simple command like :

$myArchive->putFileFromString($fileName, $dataString);

Looks like it is possible to configure PHAR with TAR & GZ, so it may be a solution?

```
$p = $p->convertToExecutable(Phar::TAR, Phar::GZ);
```

---

Bonus question, i am not sure if it would be better to build it live (after each xml string generation) to save memory, or just wait this huge object & compress it once. The ratio proc_usage / mem_usage is unclear to me in this case.

Target max usage is 100K XML files.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [Zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) and wrap it in a class if you need certain functionality?

Comment: I am not very clear with the question. You want to save all xml files into one tar.gz, but also can add new files into it? Can you make some examples?

Comment: @afuzzyllama: zlib is for .gz files, which is compression of only one single file. you need to tar up all the single files first before you can use zlib on them.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, but for future reference :

You can create a tar.gz archive using the [PharData](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) class from the the phar extension. It's a bit like the ZipArchive, except that you can add content using the Array interface :

```
$archive = new PharData("outfile.tar");
foreach ($xmlfiles as $name => $data) {
    $archive[$name] = $data;
}

// compress to "outfile.tar.gz
$gzipped = $archive->compress(Phar::GZ);

// delete outfile.tar
unset($archive);
unlink("outfile.tar");
```

Comment: However for this to work `phar.readonly` has to be set to 0 (off) in the php.ini file. You'll find that many hosts have this value set to 1 with no way to disable it, effectively making it impossible to use phar to compress files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create tgz files, use PEAR's [Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar) package. It allows you to create tar + gz files on the fly from memory:

```
require_once 'Archive/Tar.php';
$t = new Archive_Tar('/path/to/dest.tar.gz', 'gz');
foreach ($xmlfiles as $key => $content) {
    $t->addString($key . '.xml', $content);
}
```